# Difference between opencv BGR2GRAY and Pillow convert functions

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to OCR an image which includes both numbers and characters, using Tesseract library with opencv and c++. Before calling tesseract library, i used to gray scale the image with opencv

```
cvtColor(roiImg,roiImg,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

This is the [image: Gray scale image i received with python]

OCR results for this image wasn't 100% accurate.

Then the same image was tested with pillow library with python. The original image was gray scaled using the following method.

```
gray = image.convert('L')
```

This is the [image: Gray Scale image i received with pillow library]

The latter mentioned gray scaled image gave 100% accurate results.

Once i searched through the internet it was mentioned that both opencv BGR2Gray and pillow img.convert methods use the same luma transform algorithm.

What is the reason for two different OCR results?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: OpenCV uses BGR by default, but you are converting from RGB to gray (`CV_RGB2GRAY`). Shouldn't it be `CV_BGR2GRAY` ?

Comment: @Hi I'm Frogatto u are correct. I edited the code. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Still getting the same problem after @Hi I'm Frogatto suggestion?

Comment: Looks like the two libraries use the same formula to convert from color to RGB: http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_gray ; https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert The difference could be due to rounding error. You can check that by using a `16x16` image with values going from 0 to 255 and compare the results.

Comment: @NAmorim yes. Still getting the same as above mentioned.

Comment: @Catree I'm focusing on BGR to GRAY functions. Anyhow those two functions are using the same algorithm as you mentioned.

Comment: @M.Mahawatta Visually, the two grayscale images are pretty similar for me. I suspect the difference is due to OpenCV conversion being done on integer (maybe 16 bits integer for performance?) whereas Pillow conversion being done on floating point. How did you perform the OCR part? For Pillow, you convert the image in gray and then save the image which will be loaded by OpenCV + Tesseract C++? Also, there is still a typo in your OpenCV code (it should be BGR to gray not GBR to gray).

Comment: @Catree yes. As you mentioned i converted the original image into gray with pillow and then save it. It was read and stored into a mat with opencv and c++ which was then sent to tesseract functions in order to perform the OCR. The same procedure was applied with the other way where i used opencv instead of pillow to make the image gray

Answer (score 1):

[Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) can read only 3x8-bit pixels for color image.

Here a quick test to see how both libraries will round the values:

- OpenCV code:

  ```
  cv::Mat img(2, 1, CV_8UC3), img_gray;
  img.at<cv::Vec3b>(0, 0) = cv::Vec3b(248, 249, 249); //BGR
  img.at<cv::Vec3b>(1, 0) = cv::Vec3b(249, 248, 248); //BGR

  cv::cvtColor(img, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  std::cout << "img:\n" << img << std::endl;
  std::cout << "img_gray:\n" << img_gray << std::endl;

  float val1 = 249*0.299f + 249*0.587f + 248*0.114f; //RGB
  float val2 = 248*0.299f + 248*0.587f + 249*0.114f; //RGB
  std::cout << "val1=" << val1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "val2=" << val2 << std::endl;
  ```

> img:
>
> [248, 249, 249;
>
> 249, 248, 248]
>
> img_gray:
>
> [249;
>
> 248]
>
> val1=248.886
>
> val2=248.114

- Python code:

  ```
  rgbArray = np.zeros((2,1,3), 'uint8')
  rgbArray[0,0,0] = 249 #R
  rgbArray[0,0,1] = 249 #G
  rgbArray[0,0,2] = 248 #B
  rgbArray[1,0,0] = 248 #R
  rgbArray[1,0,1] = 248 #G
  rgbArray[1,0,2] = 249 #B

  img = Image.fromarray(rgbArray)
  imgGray = img.convert('L')

  print("rgbArray:\n", rgbArray)
  print("imgGray:\n", np.asarray(imgGray))
  print("np.asarray(imgGray).dtype: ", np.asarray(imgGray).dtype)
  ```

> rgbArray:
>
> [[[249 249 248]]
>
> [[248 248 249]]]
>
> imgGray:
>
> [[248]
>
> [248]]
>
> np.asarray(imgGray).dtype:  uint8